# $n^2+1$ and $n$ are coprime for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ that $\,n^2+1\,$ and $\,n\,$ are coprime.

My attempt: We have to prove that $\,n^2+1\,$ and $\,n\,$ are coprime, i.e.,
we have to prove $\gcd(n^2+1,n)=1$.

Suppose that $\gcd(n^2+1,n)=d$.
Then $d|(n^2+1)$ and $d|n$,
then $d|(n^2+1-n\cdot n) = d|(n^2+1-n^2) = d|1$

This means $d=1$.

Is my approach correct?

Comment: I think you are right.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg..thank you

Comment: I feel like this is a bit more intuitive:
Note that $GCD(n^2, n^2 + 1) = 1$.

But a prime factor $p$ divides $n^2$ if and only if $p$ divides $n$. Hence, as $p$ does not divide $n^2 + 1$, $GCD(n,n^2 + 1)=1$.

Comment: If p divide n then it divide $ n^2$ then if it divide $ n^2 + 1$ then it diivide 1...then d=1

Comment: Kind of round about: gcd (k,k+1) is always 1.  If gcd (a,b)=d and g (b,c)=1 then gcd (d,c) =1 (if d had any factors in common with c then c would have that factor in common with b).  g (n,n^2)=n, g (n^2,n^2+1)=1 so gcd (n,n^2+1)=2.  There's a million ways to do it, but basically all factors of n are factors of n^2 and therefore not of n^2 +1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another approach using euclid's algorithm. 
$$gcd(n^2+1,n)=gcd(n^2-n+1,n)=gcd(n^2-2n+1,n)....=gcd(n^2-n.n+1,n)$$
i.e
$$gcd(1,n)=1$$

Comment: That's exactly the same think OP did...

Comment: Well yes, its basically the same thing, but i felt this looked neater.

Answer (score 5):

If $d$ divides $n$ and $n^2 + 1$, then $d$ divides $n^2$
and $d$ divides $n^2 + 1 - n^2 = 1$.

Answer (score 3):

Your reasoning is fine. And basically it's taken up in the two answers until now.

My addition follows this trend: The greatest common divisor of two integers $\,p,q\,$ (not both zero) can be characterised as the smallest positive integer among the linear combinations of $p$ and $q$
$$\operatorname{gcd}(p,q)\;=\; \min \big\{\{ap+bq\mid a,b\in\mathbb Z\}\cap\mathbb N\big\}\,.$$
With $\,p=n^2+1\,$ and $\,q=n\,$ one may write
$$1\cdot(n^2+1)\,+\,(-n)\cdot n\:=\:1\:=\:\operatorname{gcd}(n^2+1,n)\,,$$
so they're coprime.

Comment: (+1) I was about to write a similar answer. This is nice because it relates to [Bezout's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity), which is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. More generally $\,\gcd(jn\!+\!k,n) = \gcd(k,n)\,$ by Euclid's algorithm (yours is case $\,j,k = n,1)$  In particular: $\,\gcd( f(n),n) = \gcd(f(0),n)\,$ for any polynomial $\,f(x)\,$ with *integer* coefficients.